# Style editText for android

Tags: java, android

I'm running Android 2.3 on my phone and notice a lot of apps using ICS edit Text fields such as square up and tumblr. Do anyone know how they are using to achieve this ?

Comment: i think the style depends on Holo theme in ics

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can apply custom style to your edit text.

Here's how:
- Create a xml file in your drawables folder (edit_text_holo_dark.xml)
- Put this xml code inside the file created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_activated_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_focused_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_focused_holo_dark" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

- Copy the drawables mentioned in the above xml from platforms folder (platform android-15) to your project's drawable folder.
- Create a styles.xml file inside your values folder and put this code:

  ```
  <style name="EditTextHoloDark" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_dark</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
  </style>
  ```
- Finally in your layout file, add style attribute to edittext:

  style="@style/EditTextHoloDark"

Answer (score 3):

[Please Read this it may help you](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) `//Dead`

Link above is invalid now, [you might take a look at this instead](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely they had copied the resources from the new platform into their app. So you need to copy files related to edit text into your app and apply those to your edit boxes. It should not be that difficult to do.